# Lodash import function not found

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, lodash, es6-modules

I am trying to import "pipe" function from lodash into my project but I get error in browser console that it's not found 404.

index.html:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Functional Programming</title>
    <script defer type="module" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <h1>Functional Programming</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-functional": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-immutable": "^1.0.0",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  }
}
```

JS file:

```js
import { pipe } from "./node_modules/lodash/fp";

const capitalize = text => text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1);
const shortenText = text => text.substring(0, 8).trim();

const shortText = pipe(capitalize, shortenText)("this is a long text");
```

[image: JS location error]

Comment: Does "pipe" function exist in Lodash?

Comment: Yes it does, actually i created new project now with vite and this import works, but i don't know why it does not work here.

Comment: Ok.. Can you try like this:
import _ from 'lodash';
and use _.pipe() to see if the function exists or not?

Comment: This might be a dumb question but did you actually run `npm install`? Also `import { pipe } from 'lodash/fp';` should work.

Comment: Yeah I used npm install, when I use "import { pipe } from 'lodash/fp' " I get an error that "Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"." I get same error when I use "import _ from 'lodash' "

Answer (score 0):

Solution of import pipe from lodash into javascript project:

```
import { pipe } from 'lodash/fp';

const capitalize = (text) => text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1);
const shortenText = (text) => text.substring(0, 8).trim();

const shortText = pipe(capitalize, shortenText)('this is a long text');

console.log(shortText);
```

for more information check this example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-zcoxit